# Making an avi file from JPG opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I'm trying to get this code to run but it's giving me segmentation error . I want to save 4 seconds worth of IP camera feed locally as an avi for further processing . I can`t seem to access a direct feed so I have to go the indirect way .

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IplImage *img;
    CvSize size;

    img = cvLoadImage(" http://192.168.1.4:1024/shot.jpg");
    size.width=img->width;
    size.height = img->height;

    CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(
        "out.avi",
        CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1') ,
        30,
        size,
        TRUE
    );
    if(writer ==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"No videowrite here !!!!"<<endl;
    }

    while(img!= NULL)
    {
        img = cvLoadImage("http://local_ip:1024/shot.jpg");
        cvWriteFrame(writer,img);
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check `if (img!=NULL)` after `img = cvLoadImage("http://local_ip:1024/shot.jpg");` in cycle `while(img!=NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

First answer is certainly helpful. You have however more problems here.
At some point you are going to `cvReleaseImage(&img);` with a NULL img!
Also, although it's perhaps not your current issue, you should also make sure that you don't `cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);` if `writer == NULL`.
This is now not handled correctly...